# Issue creating calculated field column in SQL

Tags: sql

This is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT RESERVATION.RESERVATION_ID, RESERVATION.TRIP_ID, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM, 
RESERVATION.NUM_PERSONS,RESERVATION.TRIP_PRICE
FROM RESERVATION, CUSTOMER
WHERE NUM_PERSONS > '4';
```

I need to create a column named TOTAL_PRICE that calculates the price for all the reservations with more than 4 people. I've tried multiple different ways and I'm still really confused. 
The code I have works and it shows all reservations that have more than 4 people attending. But I need the price for each reservation to be calculated in a separate column.

Comment: **Always use proper, explicit, *standard* `JOIN` syntax.**  You have no join conditions.

Comment: don't compare numbers with string values. `4`  is a number constant in SQL, `'4'`  is a character value. you should be using `num_persons > 4`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT SUM(r.TRIP_PRICE)
FROM RESERVATION r
WHERE NUM_PERSONS > 4;
```

Comment: @avery_larry . . . There should not be a group by.  I meant an aggregation query.